# AWS - Cognito Authentication - Curl Call - Generate Token Without CLI - No Client Secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, postman, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have created a API Gateway and I have applied Cognito Authentication there. Here to have the API Call work I am using AWS CLI to get Token , Here is my CLI Code

```
aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --user-pool-id us-west-2_leb660O8L --client-id 1uk3tddpmp6olkpgo32q5sd665 --auth-flow ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH --auth-parameters USERNAME=myusername,PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Now I want to use CURL Call instead of this CLI Call. I have found the code but all needs client secret here. I do not have client secret as my user pool is of Enable Signin for server-based authentication.

[image: User Pool app Client Settings]

Please guide me how I can use that.

I have gone through 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html 
[What will be the EndPoint for Calling IntiateAuth Or AdminIntiateAuth]
&
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

To Summarise this :
I want to get Id_Token Using Curl or Postman without Client Secret.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can authenticate a user with the following request.
This is the endpoint of the [InitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html) request.

Hope that this is useful for you

```
Method: POST
Endpoint: https://cognito-idp.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
X-Amz-Target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth
Body:
{
    "AuthParameters" : {
        "USERNAME" : "YOUR_USERNAME",
        "PASSWORD" : "YOUR_PASSWORD"
    },
    "AuthFlow" : "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH", // Don't have to change this if you are using password auth
    "ClientId" : "APP_CLIENT_ID"
}
```

And the response as the following

```
{
    "AuthenticationResult": {
        "AccessToken": "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN",
        "ExpiresIn": 3600,
        "IdToken": "YOUR_ID_TOKEN",
        "RefreshToken": "YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN",
        "TokenType": "Bearer"
    },
    "ChallengeParameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The Only Change I need to make was select "Enable username password based authentication (ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)" from App Setting

Answer (score 12):

Just sharing direct curl here may helpful to anyone

```
curl -X POST --data @user-data.json \
-H 'X-Amz-Target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1' \
https://cognito-idp.<just-replace-region>.amazonaws.com/
```

file json `user-data.json`

```
{"AuthParameters" : {"USERNAME" : "sadfsf", "PASSWORD" : "password"}, "AuthFlow" : "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH", "ClientId" : "csdfhripnv7sq027kktf75"}
```

make sure your app client does not contain app-secret or create new app without secret. also inside app enable `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH`

Comment: Thanks for that! I don't have `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` enabled but for postman it is still working. Can I somehow use the postman method in the cli or in curl? With the cli and `iniateAuth` it is not working

Comment: Is there a way to send the client secret?

Comment: @shresthaal The client secret can be added to the request as part of the "AuthParameters": `"AuthParameters" : {"USERNAME" : "theuser", "PASSWORD" : "thepassword", "SECRET_HASH":"jksfasjfkjfasfiowefji"}`