# AWS - Google / Cognito Authentication - cURL Call - Generate Token Without CLI

Tags: curl, amazon-cognito, google-authentication

I am new to AWS Cognito based authentication. So, thank you in advance for all the guidance you can provide.

In my company Cognito authentication is done using Google credentials. I am trying to learn how I can perform step by step cURL commands to get my Cognito Token, so I can perform other API requests which uses the token. I read AWS Cognito documentation and few Stack Overflow posts, but none of them talk about the whole flow OR combination of both.

Few links I've read so far:

- Everything under https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html
- [AWS - Cognito Authentication - Curl Call - Generate Token Without CLI - No Client Secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833462/aws-cognito-authentication-curl-call-generate-token-without-cli-no-clien/61945856#61945856)

Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: Could you give us the various documentation links that you have been reading? This might help people answer your question.

Comment: Patrick - I've updated the original question with the links. Would that be enough.