# convert curl request to aws cognito to java http request

Tags: java, curl, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to convert the [following curl request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833462/aws-cognito-authentication-curl-call-generate-token-without-cli-no-clien) (authenticate aws cognito) :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://cognito-idp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/' \
--header 'X-Amz-Target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1' \
--data-raw '{
    "AuthFlow": "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "AuthParameters": {
        "PASSWORD": "pw",
        "USERNAME": "user"
    },
    "ClientId": "the_cognito_client_id"
}'
```

to java via the java11 net library:

```
public void loginHttp(username,password,clientId) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    Map<Object,Object> credentialsMap = new HashMap<>();
    credentialsMap.put("USERNAME",username);
    credentialsMap.put("PASSWORD",password);

    Map<Object,Object> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
    requestBody.put("AuthFlow","USER_PASSWORD_AUTH");
    requestBody.put("ClientId",clientId);
    requestBody.put("AuthParameters",credentialsMap);

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"))
            .header("X-Amz-Target","AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth")
            .header("Content-Type","application/x-amz-json-1.1")
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody.toString()))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

When sending the request via postman I'm getting a response back (return code 200) but when I use the java I  get return code 400 (bad Request).

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like myMap.toString() generates the map as a string but without
quotation marks around the keys and values :

```
{
  key1 : value1
  key2 : value2
}
```

Therefore, I used Jackson`s Object mapper to convert the map to the right representation :

```
{ 
  "key1" : "value1"
  "key2" : "value2"
}
```

code :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String stringMap = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestBody)
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"))
        .header("X-Amz-Target","AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth")
        .header("Content-Type","application/x-amz-json-1.1")
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(stringMap))
        .build();
```

(notice the object mapper use in the POST method args).